# Android Studio SDK is not compatible with Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I've installed Android Studio in Windows 10. When I open Android SDK Manager and try to install 2.2 SDK platform I have the problem. It's not compatible with Windows and I can't install it. I've attached a screen shot of the problem. I can't install any version below 4.0 (API 14).

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: I also get that on OS X. I think the SDK platforms were simply removed. Why do you need them?

Comment: Looks that they removed it this week, since I've installed it last weekend, and now see same (but installed ones remains on my disk)

Comment: Why do we need them? Well, Android is now the basis for a fair amount of embedded enterprise work, and these don't follow API upgrades very closely. For example, for better or for worse, I'm stuck at API 10, and the ADT tooling doesn't like the minSdkVersion this results in unless you actually have a copy of it.

Answer (score 6):

Allright I had the same problem but managed to fix it (I believe)

Found [a website that has standalone downloads for each version](http://qdevarena.blogspot.com.es/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html)

If you download them and place them into the android-sdk/platforms folder named as "android-APINUMBER" for example version 2.1 would be "android-7" then you reload the manager and they will show as installed, hope that helps and also I hope they make them downloadable again.

Comment: This solved my problem with an old project developed in eclipse and wanted to import it to android studio, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The api level 8 is very old and according to the [api distribution](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) the distribution of api level 8 is 0.1%. Most of the libraries and apps comes today on play store will be targeting newer devices so there is no meaning of supporting devices with api level 8. So it is advisable to target `newer devices` and `newer apis` which have more features.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just 2.2 flagged as not compatible with Windows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. To solve it I clicked on `Packages` at top and clicked `Show Obsolete Packages` which then enables you to **download/install** the package

Comment: Showing obsolete packages will not enable you to download/install the package. It will still show Not compatible with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to run SDK Manager.exe in Administrator mode. You need to run it manually from the android\sdk directory. This clears the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I have resolved it the next:

1) Install jdk1.8...

2) In AndroidStudio File->Project Structure->SDK Location, select your directory where the JKD is located, by default Studio uses embedded JDK but for some reason it produces error=216.

3) Click Ok.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I encountered the same problem.
Later, I found that a security software takes up virtualization.
My solution is to turn off the use of security software for virtualization.
[Turn off!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXeoA.png)